# window.open method in chrome extension puts flags like chrome://extenstion/202324 before my specified url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, window.open

I am trying to open an external url from my extension using the window.open method but it opens a different url from what is specified.

I have tried looking for other ways to open a popup to an external url so if you know how plz tell me.

```
var tipWebsite = "www.gurvirsingh.tk/teddyprivacy/tips/" + response.currentURL.slice(4, -4);
window.open(tipWebsite);
```

For example window.open(google.com). However instead of opening a new tab or window going to google it goes to "chrome-extension://djhibahmdhdcbfbnjkggbjfnffegdoec/google.com", which obviously doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

A URL should start with a protocol, so `https://www.gurvirsingh.tk/...` or `https://google.com`. Otherwise the browser assumes it's a relative URL.